# How to pass several files to a command function and output them to different files?

Tags: r, bash, file

I have a directory made  of 50 files, here's an excerpt about how the files are names :

```
    input1.txt
    input2.txt    
    input3.txt
    input4.txt
```

I'm writing the script in R but I'm using bash commands inside it using "system"
I have a system command X that takes one file and outputs it to one file
example :

```
X input1.txt output1.txt
```

I want input1.txt to output to output1.txt, input2.txt to output to output2.txt etc..

I've been trying this:

```
    for(i in 1:50)
    {
     setwd("outputdir");
     create.file(paste("output",i,".txt",sep=""));
     setwd("homedir");
     system(paste("/usr/local/bin/command" , paste("input",i,".txt",sep=""),paste("/outputdir/output",i,".txt",sep="")));
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm getting an error at the line of system  , it says incorrect string constant , I don't get it.. Did I apply the system command in a wrong manner?

Is there a way to get all the input files and output files without going through the paste command to get them inside system?

Comment: I think you meant file.create, not create.file. Also, does your command even require that the output file be created prior to writing to it -- typically this is not the case.  `i <- 1:4; cmds <- sprintf('"%s" "%s/input%d.txt"  "%s/output%d.txt"', cmd, indir, i, outdir, i)` will create the commands all at once.

Comment: This is inside my R script?  and the cmd , is it the command I want to use? Don't I need to put "" around that like when using system?

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty easy method in R to copy files to a new directory without using the system commands. This also has the benefit of being cross-capable on different operating systems (just have to change the files structures).

Modified code from:  ["Copying files with R" by Amy Whitehead](https://www.r-bloggers.com/copying-files-with-r/)

Using your method of running for files 1:50 I have some psudocode here. You will need to change the current.folder and new.folder to something

```
# identify the folders
current.folder <- "/usr/local/bin/command"
new.folder <- "/outputdir/output"

# find the files that you want
i <- 1:50
# Instead of looping we can use vector pasting to get multiple results at once!
inputfiles <- paste0(current.folder,"/input",i,".txt")
outputfiles <- paste0(new.folder,"/output",i,".txt")

# copy the files to the new folder
file.copy(inputfiles, outputfiles)
```